# Azure Function - Report a faliure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I developed an azure function and deployed it in my subscription. Initially I had hard time setting up correct connection string and that lead Azure Function to fail functionally. But Azure reported it to be successful because the exception generated by code was handled.

[image: Azure Function Monitoring]

How do you report a failure to azure function status?

**The Status should be "failed" instead of passing.**

The problem is, operation team would not come to know about failure unless they review each logs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function execution is marked as failed if there was an uncaught exception. If there was an exception, but you handled it inside the function, it's still a success for the runtime.

To mark executions as failures, don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: This right here. If you need to take some kind of action before the process terminates then make sure to throw some kind of exception once you're done.

Comment: @Mikhail - Wouldn't this make my function faulty? Will function core runtime terminate my function and won't allow it to execute it further if it keeps failing all the time?

Comment: No, it will terminate that one INSTANCE of your function. So does a 200 OK (or successful execution). Next event that triggers your function will launch a new instance.